# How Are Speakers (and any other devices) Integrated Into the Interior of NFL Helmets (or other sports)?

Tags: american-football, helmet

I am wondering how devices, such as speakers used in NFL helmets, as sufficiently attached and setup to withstand their respective sport conditions. In the NFL, they must be able to survive numerous impacts without detaching or getting damaged, as well as environmental conditions that could damage their electronic components.

Can anyone speak to how these are mounted, how they are wired, do they use long-range bluetooth or some other type of connection, are they integrated into the helmet or an additive component post-manufacturing, can they be taken in/out for charging or maintenance or are they fixed inside, along with similar relevant information.

I'd appreciate if any materials or sources could be linked as well as I've found almost nothing regarding these devices after scouring the internet. Thank you!

**Context:** I am designing a device that will ultimately be planted inside the interior of a helmets. I won't go into much detail, but it would ideally be used football helmets, before expanding to protective headgear used in any sport. I have an almost-solidified design, but would like to draw inspiration on how devices, especially those with a similar application, are implanted and wired to function efficiently through impacts and environmental risks (moisture, dust, debris, etc.)